# I have installed python 3.8.0 but unable to find the location where it installed(Control panel showing the latest version)

Tags: windows

I have installed python 3.8.0 but unable to find the location where it installed(Control panel showing the latest version)

I am struggling to find where python install to set environment variables.
But i see the python 3.8.0 installation in control panel

Answer (score 1):

In Windows 2003 and above (I think) you have the `where` command, used simply it searches the current directory and also those included in the system `PATH` variable. Full details [at this location](https://ss64.com/nt/where.html)

```
C:\Users\Mike>where python*.exe
C:\Python27\python.exe
C:\Python27\pythonw.exe
C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.7.exe
C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.exe
```

You can use the /r switch followed by a root folder to search under; this can take a longer time if you tell it to search under the C:\ folder, and will find everything, which may be confusing:

```
C:\Users\Mike>where /r C:\ python*.exe
C:\Python27\python.exe
C:\Python27\pythonw.exe
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\Pythonwin.exe
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\win32\pythonservice.exe
C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python.exe
C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.7.exe
C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.exe
C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe\python.exe
C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe\python3.7.exe
C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppInstaller_8wekyb3d8bbwe\python3.exe
C:\Users\Mike\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Installer\{16E52445-1392-469F-9ADB-FC03AF00CD62}\python_icon.exe
```